# Get information about programs at SAS

Tags: sas

I try to get information like program name, path, date of change of all the programs I have in the SAS library. I would love to know how to do it

Comment: Usually a SAS library means SAS datasets.  Normally programs are just files.  Are you asking how to look at a directory listing for a file system?

Comment: 1. Get a list of files with info using command line. 2. Use FINFO() functions as illustrated here: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0cpuq4ew0dxipn1vtravlludjm7.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: Hi,
I try to create a function that receives as input a folder name on the computer and outputs a list of all the programs in SAS that are in the folder with information about them such as path, creation date, etc.